# Aquarium in the wall

Tags: walls

I want to build a wall with aquarium inside. This wall will divide my office from recreational room. Aquarium will be about 2 meters long and 0.7 - 0.9 m high. Width is about 50 - 60 cm.

What precautionary actions should i take before building such wall? How to make sure that this construction will be sturdy and solid, so my aquarium won't break?

**Update:**
My floor is concrete (basement), wall will be made of 2x4s and drywall. I am planning to have access to the tank from the back, so i can do maintenance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will be a lot in common with framing a window.  Here are a few things to consider:

1. Make sure the floor can support the weight of a tank full of this much water.
2. If you're on concrete, or think there's even a remote chance of moisture from the tank getting to the wall, I'd use pressure treated wood.
3. Consider how you will access the tank once it's inside the wall.  I think a false wall building out the side of a room with a closet door to access the tank from behind would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 5):

You will also need to consider the weight, not just for the floor, but also for the framing suspending the tank (presumably at eye level). Based upon the dimensions you supplied (I used the larger of each) you are looking at around 1080 liters of water. A liter of water weights about 1 kilo, so you need to support 1080 kilos (approx. 2380 pounds) of just water. Add in the weight of the aquarium, gravel, etc.

I don't have the expertise to tell you **how** to engineer it though.